# Select last rows based on increasing column value before reset?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I try to write a (postgres) sql query which returns the last rows before a specific numeric column drops below it's preceding value, for multiple `services`.

Let's say the given data looks like:

```
service | captured | online_seconds
--------+----------+---------------
A       | 01:10:00 | 500 <--
A       | 01:08:00 | 100
A       | 01:07:00 | 600 <--
A       | 01:02:00 |  50
B       | 01:09:00 | 400 <--
B       | 01:06:00 | 200
B       | 01:05:00 | 700 <--
```

The expected result would be:

```
service | captured | online_seconds
--------+----------+---------------
A       | 01:10:00 | 500
A       | 01:07:00 | 600
B       | 01:09:00 | 400
B       | 01:05:00 | 700
```

SQL Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9jZiSLa5L9tCD7pmXwFiYW/1

I was unable to find any solution until now, any ideas how this could be implemented, if possible?

Comment: You don't want this per service? I.e. you want to include the last row in your results, but not the last row for service A, because this is followed by a row with increased online seconds, no matter that it's another service. Correct?

Comment: The result should be per service, as you can see in the expected result. A and B are complete independent.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I had the times backward. The last row in the table is the first row captured. So I had it all mixed up. I've corrected my answer (i.e. added the missing partition clause).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEAD` to see the following row's data:

```
select service, captured, online_seconds
from
(
  select
    service,
    captured,
    online_seconds,
    lead(online_seconds) over (partition by service order by captured) as next_online_seconds
  from mytable
) with_next_online_seconds
where next_online_seconds < online_seconds or next_online_seconds is null
order by captured;
```

Comment: Great answer, i couldn't figure out how to correctly use the table partitioning function as for me the syntax is a way more complex than normal queries.

Comment: Yep, those window functions work quite different from other expressions. Image you have done the whole select and see the result rows. Now for every row in that result you perform the window function (`LEAD OVER`). The `PARTITION BY` clause says "look at the result rows with the same service only". The `ORDER BY` says in which order to look at the rows, `LEAD` says "give me the next row in that partition and order (or null when there is no next row).

Comment: That is also why you often see them wrapped inside one more Select, because  it's too late to filter on windowing results.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data, you want to see where the values *increase* from the value on the immediately preceding value for that service.  For that, use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(online_seconds) over (partition by service order by captured) as prev_online_seconds
      from t
     ) t
where online_seconds > prev_online_seconds
```

Comment: I don't  think that's right...   If you had a sequence 100, 200, 300, 400 you would show 200, 300, 400 but I think OP only wants to see 400

Comment: @ChrisMaurer . . . You are reading something into the question that I do not see.

Comment: That's correct what @ChrisMaurer said, i only want to see 400, the maximum before drop.